# How to add an object into an array inside a collection in MongoDB using spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a collection say, Employee

```
@Document(collection = "employee")
public class Employee{
  private int id;
  private int name;
  //setters and getters
}
```

I need to add a list in it , say jobHistory as shown below

```
@Document(collection = "employee")
public class Employee{
  @Id
  private int id;
  private int name;
  List<JobHistory> jobHostory;

  //setters and getters
}
```

And the jobHostory includes

```
public class jobHostory {
  private int id;
  private String jobtitle;
  private String companyName;
  private int noOfYears;
  
  //setters and getters
}
```

How can I add {"jobtitle" : "xxx", "companyName" : "xxx", "noOfYears" : "5"} into Employee Collection? And how the JobHistory id will autogenerate?

As I am new to MongoDB, I need some clarification further. Hope all understand.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Create an entity with `JobHistory` also, exactly in the same way as you're doing for `Employee`. Use `@Id` and something like `@GeneratedValue` to autogenerate the value of `JobHistory. Also use `@OneToMany` Mapping in `Employee` entity

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a mapping in MongoDB for this? @RamanSahasi

Comment: @sushmitha aren't you using JPA?

It will automatically create required mapping